# Javascript error calling overloaded methods of a C# class

Tags: c#, overloading, jscript.net

I'm writing a C# class library, and calling it from some Javascript code (technically Jscript.NET). I recently added some overloaded methods, and Javascript has trouble deciding which one to call, because it doesn't always know the types of its variables. I understand why this is happening in most cases, but I've got one example where I don't understand it.

Here are the overloaded method declarations in the C# class.

```
public virtual DeviceMessage RequestInUnits(
    Command command,
    int value,
    UnitOfMeasure unit)
public virtual DeviceMessage RequestInUnits(
    Command command, 
    Measurement measurement)
```

My application has a scripting feature that uses Jscript.NET. Here's some Javascript code that tries to call one of those methods on the C# class.

```
c.RequestInUnits(Command.MoveAbsolute, 0);
```

That's not a legal call, because the only method with two parameters expects a `Measurement` object as the second parameter. However, I would expect a type mismatch error. Instead, here's the compilation error I get.

```
More than one method or property matches this argument list at line 3 column 1
```

If I replace the `0` with `""`, then I get a type mismatch error. Why does Javascript think it can convert a number to an object? Why does it think it can coerce the types to more than one of those methods? Only one method takes two parameters.

This isn't a critical problem, but I don't like it when my library causes confusing error messages in calling code. I'd prefer to avoid that if I can.

Comment: It's a little bit confusing since JavaScript doesn't have method overloading... What JavaScript has to do in your argument? I got lost.

Comment: I'm writing Javascript.NET code that calls the library, @MatíasFidemraizer. My application has a scripting feature, and one of the supported languages is Javascript.NET.

Comment: Ah! I'll re-tag your question... Because you're talking about JavaScript and it's "JavaScript.NET".

Comment: What lib are you using for JavaScript programming in .NET?

Comment: .NET natively supports Javascript. You don't need any extra libraries. It comes with a command-line compiler.

Comment: OK, it's technically Jscript.NET, not Javascript. I clarified the question again, @MatíasFidemraizer.

Comment: I believe JScript.NET is very outdated. It's a .NET 1.x days product, am I wrong?

Comment: @Matias: It still exists in .NETv4. It's not commonly used, but it does get broad use in some products. Fiddler uses it for its script engine feature, for instance.